# jQuery Validate plugin - не срабатывает правило для пароля

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation

Хочу добавить некоторые требования к паролю:

> Длина пароля должна быть не менее 8 и не более 14 символо
>
> Пароль должен состоять из букв латинского алфавита (A-z), арабских цифр (0-9) и специальных символов
>
> Буквенная часть пароля должна содержать как строчные, так и прописные (заглавные) буквы
>
> Пароль должен содержать не менее одного из следующих символов:
> ( . , : ; ? ! * + % - < > @ [ ] { } / \ _ {} $ # ).

Делаю так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('form[id="reg_form"]').validate({
          rules: {
            
            password_1: {
                required: true,
                pwcheck: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 14,
            }
          },
          messages: {
            password_1: {
                minlength: 'Password must be atleast 8 characterslong'
            }
          },
          submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
          }
        });

        $.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
           return /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/.test(value) // consists of only these
               && /[a-z]/.test(value) // has a lowercase letter
               && /\d/.test(value) // has a digit
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


 <form id="reg_form" method="post" action="?">
  <input type="password" id="password_1" name="password_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Password *" required>
 </form>
```

Но метод **pwcheck** не срабатывает вообще(

Answer (score 0):

У вас древняя версия `JQuery`
Попробуйте взять версию https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js - проверил работает. Как вы не заметили ошибку JS не понятно.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <form id="reg_form" method="post" action="?">
  <input type="password" id="password_1" name="password_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Password *" required>
 </form>
 
 <script>
 $(function(){
 $('#reg_form').validate({
  rules: { 
   password_1: {
    required: true,
    pwcheck: true,
    minlength: 8,
    maxlength: 14,
   }
  },
  messages: {
   password_1: {
    minlength: 'Password must be atleast 8 characterslong'
   }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
   form.submit();
  }
 });

 $.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
    return /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/.test(value) // consists of only these
     && /[a-z]/.test(value) // has a lowercase letter
     && /\d/.test(value) // has a digit
 }, "Incorrect Password!");
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```